# Under what user is apache being run?

Tags: apache-httpd, ubuntu, permissions

So I am trying to set up owncloud and the tutorial I've been following tells me this:

Let's assume your apache runs as "www-data" (as it e.g. would under Ubuntu).

Then you should change all files to be owned by that user, like so:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /media/usbdisk/ocdata
```

Now I have a problem with the setup since I can't acces my owncloud because of my permissions.

Is there a different user that runs apache on Raspberry?

Comment: Apache is run under www-data, as is nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do that (chown). Apache is running under a different user, for a purpose. You don't want a webserver that is accessible by the whole world to have access to all files. That is in case the program has some vulnerability that can be exploited.

You as a user must add permissions to files the server is allow to read, and most importantly which files it's allowed to write to.

To give read access you use `chmod a+r file`. Most of the time this isn't needed, since this is a default permission.

To give write access to a file or folder you use `chmod a+w file`.

Comment: I need this for the configuration of owncloud as I made a directory on my hdd and I want to give the apache owner the rights etc.

Answer (score 0):

As rasbian and umbutu are both debian based, they have a lot in common, including typical apache configurations, so there are probably no problems following for one on another, other than the wisdom or lack thereof of the author.